# spring-security, testing the filter chain without webapp

Tags: spring, unit-testing, spring-security

We are using spring-security in many applications with the same configuration. So we have created a library for it.

But today I have to changes many things in this library and I would like to test it so that I'm sure to not breaking anything.

Is it a way to test the filter chain and other spring-security components (like DetailsSource) without a web application ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Spring security has very convenient API for testing with spring mvc testing
http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.1.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#test-mockmvc

Comment: Yes, I know that but I receive a `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither GenericXmlWebContextLoader nor AnnotationConfigWebContextLoader was able to detect defaults, and no ApplicationContextInitializers were declared for context configuration`. So I suppose it is because I have no webapp and that's why I'm asking the question below.

Comment: What do you mean by "have no webapp"? If you don't have webapp how do you expect to use filters?

And if you mean that you don't have webapp in test environment than you just need to create MockMvc and set WebApplicationContext and SpringSecurityFilterChain there. You can autowire both of them in your test and add to MockMvc. But of course you need to have @WebAppConfiguration annotation on your test class.

I think it would be better if you provided some code. Your configurations and your test